# getting the element from the p tag

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

How can I get the content from the `<p>` tag inside a p tag with ID `categories` using DOMDocument?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
   //error_reporting(0);
   $errmsg_arr = array();
   $errflag = false;

   function getState($string)
   {
     $ex = explode(" ",$string."  ");
     return $ex[1];
   }
   $xml = "";
   $xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
   $xml .= '
     <tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';
   $baseUrl = file_get_contents('www.myscript.com/get-listing.php');

   $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
   $domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
   $domdoc->recover=true;
   $domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
?>
```

For example, my HTML might look like:

```
<p id='categories'>Sports</p>
```

I'm trying to extract the following text:

```
Sports
```

So when I tried this:

```
$p = $domdoc->getElementById('categories')->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
```

echo $p;

It will not extract the content from the id `categories`.

How can I do it?

Comment: As a sidenote, you con't have a `p` tag inside a `p` tag [**read**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). In source-view, firefox highlights a problem in red for something like `<p id="categories">
    <p>Sports</p>
</p>`

Comment: I updated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

For that html only, you can do it like this:

```
echo $domdoc->getElementById('categories')->nodeValue;
```

Output:

> Sports

See it in action [here](https://3v4l.org/b7Gij).

---

Since you [can't have](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) a `<p>` tag inside `<p>` tag, `DOMDocument` kind goes crazy about it. Depending on the case, you could do a workaround like this:

```
$baseUrl = '
<p id="categories">
    <p>Sports</p>
</p>';

$baseUrl = str_replace('<p', '<div', $baseUrl);
$baseUrl = str_replace('<p>', '<div>', $baseUrl);
$baseUrl = str_replace('</p>', '</div>', $baseUrl);

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);

echo $domdoc->getElementById('categories')->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: If you provide more details about the given html, we can change this code to match the expectations...